# Highlight method arguments in Python with Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I was used to editing Python with Netbeans, because it was the only editor I knew that could edit Python and even added a little support.

Some time ago, I found that Sublime Text 2 suits my needs better, so I made the step.

However, there is one thing in Netbeans that is really handy, which is the highlighting of the arguments of the method.

If I have a method:

```
send_message(self, playerId, text, channel, flags=None)
```

how to change the theme of Sublime Text 2 so, that `self`, `playerId`, `text`, `channel` and `flags` are highlighted as well?

Comment: Just as a note, my search for a good Python editor ended at [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) - which is really excellent.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have PHPStorm from JetBrains, and it really is excellent, but I only have a limited amount of money, and Sublime Text is free. :)

Comment: Fair play, just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Not to mention PyCharm still doesn't have multi-cursor editing (and have taken almost 2 years working on it), a feature I can't live without ATM.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a link to a visual theme editor [here](https://github.com/aziz/tmTheme-Editor#tmtheme-editor).